# How to control the right margin of my UITextView

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uitextfield

I'm trying to use constraints in interface builder to design a simple layout for static text views within table view cells. The text should extend across the entire screen with a standard margin on leading and trailing edges.

It appears fine on iPhone in portrait, but when the device is rotated, a larger than expected right margin appears, *in some cases*, despite the constraint. This is visible in the first pair of images - where the line of text is unexpectedly broken before reaching the standard margin.

In the second pair of images, the right margin is correct (20) at the top of the view, *but larger than that in other places* - within the same text view!

[image] 
[image]

[image]
[image]

I have this in viewDidLoad

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 600
```

and

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    //        NSLog("Section %ld Row %ld", (long)[indexPath section], (long)[indexPath row]);
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

The advice seems to be - have constraints to all margins, and it should resize automatically.

If I go atomic, and just start again to build views it often fixes the problem. Is this a normal part of debugging views?

Comment: Your title is about UITextField. Where’s the text field?

Comment: UITextView - thanks+

Comment: Good but the question is still all over the place. What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: In both sets of images, there is a large right margin that does not match the constraints. Trailing space is constrained to trailing superview with a default margin. Content compression resistance priority set to required. Running the app, however, the content compresses and the large right margin also doesn't match the constraints. In the second running screen image, the margin obeys the constraints for the first two paragraphs, but then compresses the text and adds a right margin below "without modification" within the same text view. My question - how to debug these constraint issues.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I don’t know about that but personally I still don’t know what the question is. There’s a lot of talk in general terms and then the only sentence ending in a question mark is “Is this a normal part of debugging views?” Is what a what of what??? That’s not a programming question. It looks to me like this is not about constraints at all, but about attributed strings. You’ve created yours in a really ill advised way.  You need to get control of your attributed strings before doing anything else, in my opinion.

Comment: But if the question really is about where your views are ending up, well, use the View Debugger, that’s what it’s for, debugging views.

Comment: There's nothing in the view debugger unusual. No errors in log. Your answer below hits it. I didn't realise that attributed strings in IB have that sort of limitation. It explains a bunch of strange behaviour. I'll do it properly then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over your screen shots and your key remark that you're getting different right margins within the same text view, it seems to me that your issues have nothing to do with the views or constraints, but with layout of text.

It appears you're trying to design a huge attributed string within Interface Builder. That's not going to work. The attributed string designer in Interface Builder is not good for much, and certainly not for extended work.

Do this the right way: design and display your attributed text in some other way. Load a file at launch and populate the interface in code. You can design your text in HTML with CSS and lay it out in a WKWebView, or you can design your text in RTF (or HTML) and load it as an NSAttributedString and put it into a text view. You can even construct the text entirely in code, from scratch, as an NSMutableAttributedString! But either way, you need to get control of your text so that you know and control what it is and what the paragraph margins are.

In a sense, this is a failure of basic MVC. Interface Builder is about building your *interface*: "a text view goes here". That's *view*. What goes *into* the text view is *model*: it's your *data*. You cannot design *data* in Interface Builder. Learn to construct and display attributed text or HTML *in code*.